# How get UI culture of application in Attribute ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have this resource localizable attribute:

```
    public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceId)
        : base(GetMessageFromResource(resourceId))
    {

    }

    private static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceId)
    {
        var ioc = Abp.Dependency.IocManager.Instance;
        var localizationManager = ioc.IocContainer.Resolve<ILocalizationManager>();


        return localizationManager.GetString(MMMConsts.LocalizationSourceName, resourceId, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);}
```

When I switch language in WEB app, and debug this, In Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture i still the same value.

But when do this in Razor view culture has changed correctly.

How can I setUp currencu culture in my attribute class , I need it for loading multilanguages texts from resources.

Model attributes are initialized before app start ? Thanks for help !

SOLVED by this code:

```
        public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey)
        : base(resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            string value = null;
            var ioc = Abp.Dependency.IocManager.Instance;
            var localizationManager = ioc.IocContainer.Resolve<ILocalizationManager>();
            value = localizationManager.GetString(MMConsts.LocalizationSourceName, ResourceKey, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);

            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the answer as answer and don't edit the question for posting answer. It makes the question and answer more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by this code:

```
  public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey)
        : base(resourceKey)
    {
    ResourceKey = resourceKey;
}

public string ResourceKey { get; set; }

public override string DisplayName
{
    get
    {
        string value = null;
        var ioc = Abp.Dependency.IocManager.Instance;
        var localizationManager = ioc.IocContainer.Resolve<ILocalizationManager>();
        value = localizationManager.GetString(MMConsts.LocalizationSourceName, ResourceKey, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);

        return value;
    }
}
```